# Sonarqube can't access for local user(LAN)

Tags: windows, sonarqube

I have installed Sonarqube 4.5.1 in my windows 07 desktop and i can access in my desktop. URL is localhost:9000
my ip address is 192.168.0.4:9000/.
When im trying to access in other system which is connect in LAN its not working.
What the setting i missed ? please help me

Comment: Have you modified anything in the sonar.properties file? I've just tried this on my box, and it's working perfectly fine. You might also have some network / firewall configuration on your Windows that prevents this.

Comment: No i didt change anything in sonar.properties file. do you want me to show the file?

Comment: I have installed Jenkins and its access by the local users(LAN), Im wondering with this SonarQube... :-( wy not its loading in LAN..

Comment: Well, I don't see what the problem could be...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows firewall is blocking the 9000 port by default. You have to disable your firewall or enable the in- and outcoming data on that port.

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-open-a-port-in-the-windows-7-firewall.html